# Producing figures in PDF and PNG format with TikZDevice and pgfSweave in Sweave

Tags: sweave, r

I use the following Sweave template to get R output into LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\SweaveOpts{pdf=TRUE, png=FALSE, eps=FALSE, echo=FALSE, prefix=FALSE, width=6, height=6, res=300}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


<<>>=
data(airquality)

\begin{center}
<<label=FigureLabel, fig=TRUE, include=FALSE>>=
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=17cm, height=17cm]{FigureLabel}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:figLabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This Sweave template produces R graphs in PDF format.  With `png=TRUE` in SweaveOpts I can also get R graphs in PNG format.

Now I'm inclined to use `TikZDevice` and `pgfSweave`. As I know `TikZDevice` and `pgfSweave` produce TeX documents only not PDF. I wonder if there is a way to get figures in PDF and PNG format using SweaveOpts in some way. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/), a "drop-in replacement" for Sweave. With standard settings, it produces a .tex file with TikZ code that is then compiled to PDF and included in your document, automagically.